# Increment a cell by a value in another cell, each click on button or check box

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I need to increment the value in a cell by the set value in some other cell, each time I click a macro button, or alternately clicking a check box.

I tried various formulas but they always return a circular error.
I looked at multiple replacement/increment macros but none do what I need or worked as described.

I'm good at formulas, but my VBA skills are very rudimentary at best.

Answer (score 0):

Put an ActiveX button on the worksheet with Developer ► Insert ► ActiveX Controls ► Command button. Right click the button and choose View Code. Modify the code to the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    [a1] = [a1] + [a2]
End Sub
```

Tap [Alt]+Q to return to your worksheet. Turn off Developer ► Design Mode. Every time you click the button, the value of A2 will be added to A1.

Comment: That worked nicely, thanks. Now how do I use range names instead of cell refs?